# R: Help using group_by( ) then mutate( ) to add a column into the df counting data up

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, data-cleaning, mutate

I have a data frame where the data is chunked into blocks of 10 trials. The data frame does not have a "trial_within_block" variable and I want to add one. I have used the following code:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(subject, block) %>%
  mutate(trial_within_block = c(1:10))
```

And this works great! However, sometimes the subjects did not finish their last block, so sometimes their last block only has 5-9 trials. When this happens, it throws an error saying:

> "Error in `mutate()`:
> ℹ In argument: `trial_within_block = c(1:10)`.
> Caused by error:
> ! `trial_within_block` must be size 7 or 1, not 10.

Is there a way to count up 1 through 10, but then on blocks that have less than 10, for it to stop?

Comment: Try `data <- data %>% group_by(subject, block) %>% mutate(trial_within_block = row_number())`

Comment: or simply `trial_within_block = 1:n()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data <- data %>%
 group_by(subject, block) %>%
 mutate(trial_within_block = 1:length(block))
```

This should work!